# RESTful iOS app - When to update model - best practices

Tags: ios, rest, model-view-controller

Let's look at a typical RESTful iOS app, let's say a contact app, main screen is the list of contacts, when tapping on a contact you get to the contact detail screen.

The contact list is obtained through a REST API, and the contact details through another API.

Which event would you use to trigger the call to those APIs:

- `viewDidAppear` on both view controllers
- `viewWillAppear` on both view controllers
- From the main view controller, call the contact detail API before calling the `pushViewController:detailViewController`
- Any other events?

Currently I am using `viewWillAppear` mostly for this kind of scenario, or `viewDidAppear` in some specific cases, but in an effort to standardize my coding practices, I would like to definitely settle on the pros/cons of those various approaches.

Answer (score 3):

It's partly a matter of preference.  Since the API call will generate an unknown delay, the app should present UI that indicates it's busy.  My preference is to have the UI do as much as possible before the request.  (My naive model of cognition is that looking at the new VC's UI while it's fetching data will occupy user's mind for an instant, making the lag seem that much shorter).

So I favor paramaters to the VCs that describe the request - like the id of the contact to be fetched on the detail VC, and do the request on viewDidAppear (if the data isn't already cached or needs a refresh).  In that method, put up some UI to indicate the fetch is happening, so it has the form:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (/* i don't have my model or it's out of date */) {
        // put up 'i am busy' UI
        MyRequestClass *request = // form a request that fetches my model
        [request runWithBlock:^(id result, NSError *error) {
            // i build my request classes to run with blocks simplifying the caller side
            // if it's a json request, then pass a parsed result back to this block
            // remove 'i am busy' UI
            if (!error) {
                // init my model from result
                // other parts of this class observe that the model changes and updates the UI
            } else {
                // present error UI
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the request is asynchronous, I would send it out **before** doing any of the UI. Then set up and display the UI with some kind of "fetching data..." placeholder, then fill out the fields when the data arrives.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's good practice to ensure your API interface and data access is happening outside of your view controllers in a separate data access class (or data controller - if you're already doing this then apologies, and ignore this paragraph). You want to *avoid* putting networking code directly into your view controller, because it's going to make your life very difficult if you either want to create an iPad specific view or need to revamp your UI in some way later on down the line).

With that out of the way, you have several options. In terms of performance from the *user's* perspective, it's best to pre-fetch as much from your RESTful API as you can. This is what libraries such as `AFIncrementalStore` that map your API to Core Data try to do. But if you have many thousands of contacts, are heavily rate limited, or bandwidth constrained this is going to be problematic.

What's absolutely certain is that you want to make the call to your networking API *as soon as possible* so that the user experiences minimal delay. You may find using `viewDidLoad` rather than `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` may work better in this case: you can set your view up with a loading/holding graphic or animation, trigger your asynchronous networking call, and then once complete display the required information.

Comment: Correct, we agree that all API interface and networking code is handled outside the view controllers. I like to have 'model controller' classes that handle all that, with notifications being sent to the view controllers whenever data is done updating. I am also pre-fetching using AFIncrementalStore in some projects, using RESTkit Core Data integration in some others. I am never making any such calls in viewDidLoad though, as in most cases it is being called only once, even if the view controller is reused through the navigation.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I was thinking about your very specific example (a detail view in a `UITableView`, where you'd end up creating a new one for each contact requested. If you're re-using your VCs then you may as well put it in `viewWillAppear`, unless you want to get particularly clever about it and start pre-fetching based on where the user is in the table, etc etc. That's probably premature optimization though.

Comment: You make interesting points here.  I agree prefetching might sometimes be a good idea, but in the case where something wasn't prefetched, I guess I have the opposite opinion about "as soon as possible".  My view, (based on loads of research that I just made up in my head) is that putting up the next UI takes virtually no time, and the user's time absorbing that new UI gets subtracted from her perception of the lag on the server request.  If I'm right, then this argues for "as late as possible, after every almost-instant change to the UI is done".  But again, this may be just my own pop-cog-sci

Comment: danh, not sure I udnerstand your comment. If the request is sent asynchronously, it takes virtually no time to start it, wouldn't it be better then to start it in viewWillAppear so some of the request is bein processed as the presentation animation is taking place?

Comment: @lxt I think even in the case of the contact detail example, I could later think of one more level when selecting something in the contact detail view. Then when navigating back to the contact detail view, viewDidLoad would not be called, even though I may want a refresh at that point. Not trying to be difficult, but trying to figure out the way that is virtually foolproof for every similar project, rather than having it in viewDidLoad for 1 project, viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear in another one. It makes things confusing when trying to remember why I picked each one when revisiting the code

Comment: @JPHribovsek - yes, it takes virtually no time to start the request... that's the same amount of time that passes between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear (virtually none), so there's no advantage to be had there, either.  My point is to be sure the view is presented to the user while the request is being fulfilled (the slow part).  viewWillAppear will do that too, but I think viewDidAppear makes my intent more clear to the reader (here and in code).

Comment: @danh I understand your point. But if you're using Core Data for caching, you will actually see a difference between viewWillAppear (which will nicely display the cached data immediately) and the viewDidAppear which will display the cached data at the end of the screen presentation, which causes a little flickering effect. So I would rather go with viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

Load the contacts on viewWillAppear, and if you have pull-to-refresh, when that happens.

When user taps on a cell, in the method that handles that event, load event details, and pass that object to the contact details controller's constructor, and push it.